# is there any CustomView that lets you pick any colour

Tags: android, colorbox, android-custom-view, color-picker

Is there any CustomView available for android that shows a disc of colours (Preferably) or a grid of colours and lets you pick a colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the color picker from the [API demoes](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ColorPickerDialog.html).